# Invalid operand to binary *

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

float length() {
    float length;
    printf("Input Length: ");
    scanf("%f", &length);
    return length;
}

float width(){
    float width;
    printf("Input Width: ");
    scanf("%f", &width);
    return width;
}

float area(){
    float area=length * width;
    return area;
}

float perimeter(){
    float perimeter=(length*2) + (width*2);
    return perimeter;
}

int main(){
    printf("Area = %f\n", area());
    printf("Perimeter = %f\n", perimeter());
}
```

Invalid Operand under Area and Perimeter
skafhasfhsafsakhfsakfhasfkhsafksahfakshfaskfhasfkshfaskfhsfashfkashfasfhasfhasfksahfasfasfasfasfsfsfsfas

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `length` and `width`? If they're declared as `float` as you claim, this code compiles.

Comment: Where are they declared?

Comment: You could probably get rid of the downvote if you edit your question with the declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is quick fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float width(){
    float width;
    printf("Input Width: ");
    scanf("%f", &width);
    return width;
}

float length(){
    float length;
    printf("Input Length: ");
    scanf("%f", &length);
    return length;
}

float area() {
   return length() * width();
}

float perimeter(){
    float perimeter=(length()*2) + (width()*2);
    return perimeter;
}

int main(){
    printf("Area = %f\n", area());
    printf("Perimeter = %f\n", perimeter());
}
```

but here is how would I do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float width(){
   float width;
   printf("Input Width: ");
   scanf("%f", &width);
   return width;
}

float length(){
   float length;
   printf("Input Length: ");
   scanf("%f", &length);
   return length;
}

float area(float length, float width) {
   return length * width;
}

float perimeter(float length, float width){
   return length*2 + width*2;
}

int main(){
   float l = length();
   float w = width();
   printf("Area = %f\n", area(l, w));
   printf("Perimeter = %f\n", perimeter(l, w));
}
```

Comment: This "quick solution" suffers from the same errors as the OP's post.

Comment: Well, yes, this would give the correct output, but requires duplication of input by the user. (Which is almost never a good idea.)

Comment: @owacoder I know I would not do it this way in a million years but it was quick fix of OPs code.

Comment: so @EarldelMar what is this `return length << 1 + width << 1;`?

Comment: Well, a shift left by one is **usually** equal to a multiplication by 2. Unless you're using floating point numbers. In which case it doesn't work.

Comment: @owacoder is right it would not work in this case and he is right that this is bit shifting.

Comment: There's a typo in your perimeter function (unclosed parentheses, or unnecessary parentheses, plus both parameters are misspelled). While I'm here, I'll throw my hat in the ring for: obviously the first one is subpar and not what we'd want in production code, but it was a quick fix, and I think it's alright to point out the quick fix.

Comment: `float length = length();` fails, you cannot call a float

Comment: the code has still an error, it says 'length and width are not a function (under int main)

Answer (score 2):

`length` and `width` in `area` and `perimeter` are computed as function pointers, for which multiplication is not defined.

Comment: Either make global variables holding the length and width (easy, but not recommended) or modify `area` and `perimeter` to take parameters specifying length and width (harder, but more maintainable).